# Having trouble upgrading Ruby Version when pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment, version

I'm a beginner to Ruby and Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to deploy my app to heroku using git heroku push main.

I'm getting the following error

```
    remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
    remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.

    remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
    remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
    remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.21/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::RubygemsIntegration::EXT_LOCK
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:12: warning: previous definition of EXT_LOCK was here
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.21/lib/bundler/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::VERSION
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/version.rb:10: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.21/lib/bundler/constants.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::WINDOWS
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/constants.rb:4: warning: previous definition of WINDOWS was here
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.21/lib/bundler/constants.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::FREEBSD
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/constants.rb:5: warning: previous definition of FREEBSD was here
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.21/lib/bundler/constants.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::NULL
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/constants.rb:6: warning: previous definition of NULL was here
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.21/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::CurrentRuby::KNOWN_MINOR_VERSIONS
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/current_ruby.rb:12: warning: previous definition of KNOWN_MINOR_VERSIONS was here
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.21/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb:26: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::CurrentRuby::KNOWN_MAJOR_VERSIONS
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/current_ruby.rb:24: warning: previous definition of KNOWN_MAJOR_VERSIONS was here
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.21/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb:28: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::CurrentRuby::KNOWN_PLATFORMS
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/current_ruby.rb:26: warning: previous definition of KNOWN_PLATFORMS was here
    remote:  !     rake aborted!
    remote:  !     NoMethodError: undefined method `flat_map' for "cat config/database.yml":String
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/database_configurations.rb:168:in `build_configs'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/database_configurations.rb:19:in `initialize'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:168:in `new'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:168:in `for_each'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:232:in `in_namespace'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:141:in `namespace'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:29:in `block in <main>'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:232:in `in_namespace'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:141:in `namespace'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:9:in `<main>'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:77:in `load'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:77:in `load'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `block in load'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `load'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:49:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:263:in `instance_exec'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:263:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:275:in `each'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:275:in `each_registered_block'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:263:in `run_tasks_blocks'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:15:in `each'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:15:in `each'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `run_tasks_blocks'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `load_tasks'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/Rakefile:6:in `<main>'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
    remote:  !     /tmp/build_f6716a79/bin/rake:5:in `<main>'
    remote:  !
```

I am getting  a warning saying my Ruby version has to be updated to 2.6.7, despite the fact fact when I type ruby-v my ruby version comes up as
ruby 3.0.1p64 (2021-04-05 revision 0fb782ee38) [x86_64-darwin20]

I'd prefer it to be '3.0.1' without the 'p64 (2021-04-05 revision 0fb782ee38) [x86_64-darwin20]';

Every time I try to update it to 2.6.7 I get an error

Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /Users/nilsvanderwerf/.rvm/log/1625208421_ruby-2.6.7/make.log

My make log has this

```
    +__rvm_make:0> make -j8
        BASERUBY = /Users/nilsvanderwerf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.1/bin/ruby --disable=gems
        CC = gcc
        LD = ld
        LDSHARED = gcc -dynamiclib
        CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wmisleading-indentation -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens   -fno-common -pipe 
        XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT -DCANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN
        CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin20 -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/12.1.0 
        DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -install_name /Users/nilsvanderwerf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.7/lib/libruby.2.6.dylib -compatibility_version 2.6 -current_version 2.6.7  -fstack-protector-strong -framework Security -framework Foundation  -fstack-protector-strong -framework Security -framework Foundation  
        SOLIBS = -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lobjc
        LANG = en_US.UTF-8
        LC_ALL = 
        LC_CTYPE = 
    Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
    Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.5.0
    Thread model: posix
    InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
    compiling ./main.c
    compiling dmydln.c
    compiling miniinit.c
    compiling dmyext.c
    compiling miniprelude.c
    translating probes probes.d
    compiling ast.c
    compiling bignum.c
    compiling class.c
    compiling compar.c
    . ./vm_opts.h
    compiling compile.c
    compiling complex.c
    compiling cont.c
    compiling debug.c
    compiling debug_counter.c
    compiling dir.c
    compiling dln_find.c
    compiling encoding.c
    compiling enum.c
    compiling enumerator.c
    compiling error.c
    compiling eval.c
    compiling file.c
    compiling gc.c
    compiling hash.c
    compiling inits.c
    compiling io.c
    compiling iseq.c
    compiling load.c
    compiling marshal.c
    compiling math.c
    making mjit_config.h
    compiling mjit_compile.c
    compiling node.c
    compiling compiling numeric.c
    object.c
    compiling pack.c
    compiling parse.c
    compiling proc.c
    compiling process.c
    compiling random.c
    compiling range.c
    compiling rational.c
    compiling re.c
    compiling regcomp.c
    compiling regenc.c
    compiling regerror.c
    compiling regexec.c
    compiling regparse.c
    compiling regsyntax.c
    compiling ruby.c
    compiling safe.c
    compiling signal.c
    compiling sprintf.c
    In file included from sprintf.c:1255:
    ./vsnprintf.c:832:8: warning: adding 'int' to a string does not append to the string [-Wstring-plus-int]
                                IS_PRI_EXTRA_MARK(fmt)) {
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ./vsnprintf.c:825:34: note: expanded from macro 'IS_PRI_EXTRA_MARK'
            strncmp((s)+1, PRI_EXTRA_MARK+1, \
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
    ./vsnprintf.c:832:8: note: use array indexing to silence this warning
    ./vsnprintf.c:825:34: note: expanded from macro 'IS_PRI_EXTRA_MARK'
            strncmp((s)+1, PRI_EXTRA_MARK+1, \
                                            ^
    compiling st.c
    compiling strftime.c
    compiling string.c
    compiling struct.c
    1 warning generated.
    compiling symbol.c
    compiling thread.c
    compiling time.c
    compiling transcode.c
    compiling transient_heap.c
    compiling util.c
    compiling variable.c
    ./revision.h unchanged
    compiling vm.c
    vm.c:2295:9: error: implicit declaration of function 'rb_native_mutex_destroy' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            rb_native_mutex_destroy(&vm->waitpid_lock);
            ^
    vm.c:2489:34: warning: expression does not compute the number of elements in this array; element type is 'const int', not 'VALUE' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsizeof-array-div]
                                sizeof(ec->machine.regs) / sizeof(VALUE));
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
    vm.c:2489:34: note: place parentheses around the 'sizeof(VALUE)' expression to silence this warning
    1 warning and 1 error generated.
    make: *** [vm.o] Error 1
    make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    +__rvm_make:0> return 2
```

I've also tried rvm reinstall all --force but I'm getting

```
Error running 'env GEM_HOME=/Users/nilsvanderwerf/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1@global GEM_PATH= /Users/nilsvanderwerf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.1/bin/ruby -d /Users/nilsvanderwerf/.rvm/src/rubygems-3.0.9/setup.rb --no-document',
please read /Users/nilsvanderwerf/.rvm/log/1625211120_ruby-3.0.1/rubygems.install.log
```

When I run rvm list

```
rvm list
ruby-2.6.1 [ missing bin/ruby ]
ruby-2.6.3 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-3.0.1 [ x86_64 ]
```

I'd like to completely uninstall Ruby and upgrade to 2.6.7, without the platform x86_64-darwin20 (can't remember why I installed this in the first place)

Please give your answer in laymans terms as I've trawled threads and have been unable to make sense of them
Also, let me know if the Ruby version is not the issue.
Thanks.

****EDIT ****
My Gemfile and Gemlock is below

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.1'
gem 'bundler', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.4'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.3', '>= 6.1.3.2'
gem 'pg'
# gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4' REPLACE BACK
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'


# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem "omniauth", "~> 1.9.1"
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails' # For showing calender in date fields insane


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'pry'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

---

Gemlock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      actionview (= 6.1.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.1.4)
      actionview (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.9)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
    activerecord (6.1.4)
      activemodel (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
    activestorage (6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      marcel (~> 1.0.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activesupport (6.1.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.16)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.7.5)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    bootstrap-datepicker-rails (1.9.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    capybara (3.35.3)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    coderay (1.1.3)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.9)
    crass (1.0.6)
    devise (4.8.0)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    dotenv (2.7.6)
    dotenv-rails (2.7.6)
      dotenv (= 2.7.6)
      railties (>= 3.2)
    erubi (1.10.0)
    faraday (1.4.3)
      faraday-em_http (~> 1.0)
      faraday-em_synchrony (~> 1.0)
      faraday-excon (~> 1.1)
      faraday-net_http (~> 1.0)
      faraday-net_http_persistent (~> 1.1)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
      ruby2_keywords (>= 0.0.4)
    faraday-em_http (1.0.0)
    faraday-em_synchrony (1.0.0)
    faraday-excon (1.1.0)
    faraday-net_http (1.0.1)
    faraday-net_http_persistent (1.1.0)
    ffi (1.15.3)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    hashie (4.1.0)
    i18n (1.8.10)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.11.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    jquery-rails (4.4.0)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jwt (2.2.3)
    listen (3.5.1)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    loofah (2.10.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (1.0.1)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mini_mime (1.1.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.5.3)
    minitest (5.14.4)
    msgpack (1.4.2)
    multi_json (1.15.0)
    multi_xml (0.6.0)
    multipart-post (2.1.1)
    nio4r (2.5.7)
    nokogiri (1.11.7)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.5.0)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    oauth2 (1.4.7)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 2.0)
      jwt (>= 1.0, < 3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (>= 1.2, < 3)
    omniauth (1.9.1)
      hashie (>= 3.4.6)
      rack (>= 1.6.2, < 3)
    omniauth-facebook (8.0.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.7.1)
      oauth2 (~> 1.4)
      omniauth (>= 1.9, < 3)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (1.2.3)
    pry (0.14.1)
      coderay (~> 1.1)
      method_source (~> 1.0)
    public_suffix (4.0.6)
    puma (5.3.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.5.2)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-mini-profiler (2.3.2)
      rack (>= 1.2.0)
    rack-proxy (0.7.0)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.1.4)
      actioncable (= 6.1.4)
      actionmailbox (= 6.1.4)
      actionmailer (= 6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      actiontext (= 6.1.4)
      actionview (= 6.1.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4)
      activemodel (= 6.1.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 6.1.4)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.13)
      thor (~> 1.0)
    rake (13.0.3)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.0)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (2.1.1)
    responders (3.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    ruby2_keywords (0.0.4)
    rubyzip (2.3.0)
    sass-rails (6.0.0)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
    sassc (2.4.0)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    semantic_range (3.0.0)
    spring (2.1.1)
    sprockets (4.0.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (1.1.0)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    warden (1.2.9)
      rack (>= 2.0.9)
    web-console (4.1.0)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (4.6.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    webpacker (5.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 5.2)
      semantic_range (>= 2.3.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.4.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (>= 1.4.4)
  bootstrap-datepicker-rails
  bundler (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.4)
  byebug
  capybara (>= 3.26)
  devise
  dotenv-rails
  jbuilder (~> 2.7)
  jquery-rails
  listen (~> 3.3)
  omniauth (~> 1.9.1)
  omniauth-facebook
  pg
  pry
  puma (~> 5.0)
  rack-mini-profiler (~> 2.0)
  rails (~> 6.1.3, >= 6.1.3.2)
  sass-rails (>= 6)
  selenium-webdriver
  spring
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  web-console (>= 4.1.0)
  webdrivers
  webpacker (~> 5.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.0.1p64

BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.21
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include your gemfile & gemfile.lock?

Comment: Remember, you are pushing to heroku, so the version installed on your machine is not relevant. The ruby version specified in your Gemfile(.lock) is what Heroku uses. Heroku's supported runtime for 2.6.x is 2.6.7; if your specified ruby version is different (say, 2.6.0), Heroku will warn you to upgrade.

Comment: @Ted My GemLock and Gemfile are edited in

Comment: Also its worth mentioning that when I try to include 2.6.7 in my gemfile and bundle install it has the error "Your Ruby version is 3.0.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.7" 


When I try to install 2.6.7 using rvm install it tells me Error running '__rvm_make -j8', please read /Users/nilsvanderwerf/.rvm/log/1625208421_ruby-2.6.7/make.log"
When I try to uninstall ruby to do a fresh install using "sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/ruby" it tells me "rm: /usr/bin/ruby: Operation not permitted"